# How can I echo nested variables inside a for loop?

Tags: batch-file

Here is a for loop to save each line of a text file to its own variable:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions enableDelayedExpansion 

set count=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (file.txt) do (
    set /a count=!count! + 1
    set var_!count!=%%a
)

endlocal
```

I would like to save the content of each variable to a separate new text file. How can I do this? I tried the following. But it does not work, because !var_!count!! is a variable inside a variable.

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions enableDelayedExpansion 

set count=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (file.txt) do (
    set /a count=!count! + 1
    set var_!count!=%%a
    echo !var_!count!!>file_!count!.txt
)

endlocal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions enableDelayedExpansion 

set count=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (file.txt) do (
    set /a "count+=1"
    set "var_!count!=%%a"
    for %%b in (!count!) do >file_!count!.txt echo !var_%%b!
)

endlocal
```

Comment: that was fast! thanks a lot, works great! what a funny workaround :)